# Redirect to index file

Tags: php, html

```
header('location:index.php');
```

this redirected to www.website.com/index.php 
I want redirect to www.website.com/
So use

```
header('location:');
```

But this not work

Comment: header('location:.');                                   I got the answer, someone please close my question

Answer (score 0):

you may want to use [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/en/mod/mod_rewrite.html)
something like the in your .htaccess should do the trick

```
RewriteRule ^a$ about.php
```

or

```
    RewriteRule ^a$ about.php&%{QUERY_STRING}
```

if yo want to keep arguments.
also i don't think you meant to say www.web.com/about **.com**

Comment: Answers are supposed to _answer_ the question. Not give a point into the right direction. That's what comments are for!

Comment: sorry, but I can't actually comment, need 50 of reputation, what should I do?

Comment: This is not the expected answer. I told that I want the reverse of these. When we enter /about.php it should show only /about

Answer (score 0):

u can use this code for .htaccess and for link use www.web.com/about

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on

## handler view
RewriteRule ^about$ about.php [L]
```